# How to save to two models at once using Rails and has_many through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

In my rails 3.2 site I have Users and Communities. When a User creates a new Community I want the User to also automatically become a Member of that Community. Memberships form another model. The relationships are as follows:

User:

```
has_many :memberships
has_many :communities, :through => :memberships
```

Community:

```
has_many :memberships
has_many :users, :through => :memberships
```

Membership:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :community
```

In a nutshell then, how do I create a Membership at the same time as I create a Community using the user_id and membership_id obviously?

Update

Controller action:

```
def create
  @community = Community.new(params[:community])

  respond_to do |format|
  if @community.save
    format.html { redirect_to @community, notice: 'Community was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @community, status: :created, location: @community }
    else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @community.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working answer was this:

```
def create
  @community = current_user.communities.create(params[:community])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @community ...
```

The problem was using build and then @community.save. This did not save the association. Using .create automatically calls new and save and creates the association.

Answer (score 1):

This should work if a user creates a community like this:

```
user.communities.create
```

[From the Rails guide:](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

> The collection of join models can be managed via the API. For example, if you assign
>
> `physician.patients = patients`
>
> new join models are created for newly associated objects, and if some are gone their rows are deleted.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain how this would look in the controller.

Comment: sure.. add your controller to your question.

Comment: Can you access the user through `current_user` (if you have added that method for authentication)? if so: `@community = current_user.communities.build(params[:community])`

Comment: You need some way of finding the user who is creating the community.

Comment: Yes I have current_user. And the code does not create an error but it also doesn't create the association; just the new community. I need the new community and the association to be saved.

Comment: you have to call `current_user.save` in place of `@community.save`. This will mean all three records are updated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43671/discussion-between-benjaminjosephw-and-finnjon)